# Same list of videos always being returned by Youtube search query

Tags: java, android, video, youtube

I am developing an application that will play Youtube videos. My need is that when a user types any keyword that related videos for the keyword need to be displayed. However it seems that currently no matter what keyword is typed, when executed the response contains only videos  about 'android'. If anyone know how to solve this, I would appreciate some help. Below is my code:

```
public void searchData(View v) {
    ev = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
        String appPackageName = getPackageName();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
        intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
        intent.putExtra("query", "Android");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doing as expected. Because you are setting the query as :

```
intent.putExtra("query","Android");
```

it shows only android related stuff.

Try putting the user entered values there instead:

```
intent.putExtra("query",ev.getText());
```

**UPDATE :**

After OP verified that the below line works fine :

```
intent.putExtra("query",ev.getText().toString());
```

Comment: thanks Abu....let me try...that was my doubt ...i just edit android and put " " .but it didn't work....

Comment: now...also..it is not working nw it is getting result..like..app stopped working unexpectdly...

Comment: try this : `intent.putExtra("query",ev.getText().toString());`

Comment: thanks abu...for patience..but it is also not working....I am checking in my mobile..

Comment: can you post the logcat stack trace?

Comment: Thanks..Abu it is working.....we need to pt like intent.putExtra("query",ev.getText().toString()); as you said...thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

```
intent.putExtra("query","Android");
```

You have hardcoded the query string to Android

Comment: How to write the code..can u pls help..intent.putExtra("query",ev.getText());  i did like this but nw also it s not working...